# Magento 2 Move related product above Product info tabs

Tags: layout, theme, magento2.4

i want to move , related product before product tabs, as highlighted by line in image.

I tried below code but it seems not working and even the related product section is not showing:

```
<move element="content.aside" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to move related product above product info tab  on product detail page.
> Go to **catalog_product_view.xml** file

```
<move element="product.info.details" destination="content.aside"  after="catalog.product.related"/>
```

> This will move related product above product info tabs.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this,**

```
  <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" before="product.info.details" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
```

And if it comes under "add to cart" use this

```
.your-block-class{clear:both;}
```

Comment: this is moving relates block above to top